# Formula to calculate how much should be added to the x and y to move to a new point (On a rotated square)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations

[image: The diagram]

Hey!

(please see the diagram before reading the question)

i have this square ABCD which is 10x10cm and it is rotated 45 degrees clockwise

i need to move it 25 cm (so to square EHGF) over the red lines lines (AF and CG)

but i cant slide it over those lines, instead i need to move it an X amount to the left and an Y amount up to get to the square EHGF

is there a formula to calculate how much X and Y are in this case?

i am looking for a formula that always works no matter how much the square is rotated

All help is very appreciated!

Comment: Are you rotating clockwise or counterclockwise?

Comment: First of all: the relationship between the side of a square S and its diagonal D is $D=\sqrt{2}S$. Therefore, the side of the grid squares is $a=\tfrac13 \sqrt{10}$. Now the solution in the case of a 45° orientation:  you must make a $-a$ move on the left and a $+2a$ move upwards, followed by a $3a$ move on the right.

Comment: Is the positive $x$ direction really to the left?

Comment: @davidk clockwise

Comment: @a-bad The move is in the direction of AB - you could use the coordinates of A and B to define the vector of motion. The coordinates of A and B determine the angel of rotation so its actual value is not even needed. If they are not given, but the angle and size of square side and the amount of motion (point E for A?) - than use tag function. For your specific case, you just need to add $25/\sqrt{2}$ to the (x,y) value of the ABCD values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do this.

If you know the angle of rotation, you can use trigonometry to calculate the $x$ and $y$ components of the desired motion.
In this example, before rotation you would have started with $B$ directly above $A$
(at the same $x$ coordinate), and you then rotated $45$ degrees clockwise to get to the position shown.

In general, suppose you rotate by an angle $\theta$ clockwise,
and then you want to move by a distance $d$ in the rotated direction.
(In the figure it appears that $d$ is $15$. You say $25$ in the question.
Using a symbol $d$ for the distance means you can make the distance anything
you want; just make sure you set $d$ to the desired distance from $A$ to $E$.)
Then the amount to add to $y$ is
$$ d \cos(\theta) $$
(assuming positive $y$ is upward in the figure,
the direction from $C$ to $B$, as implied in the question)
and the amount to add to $x$ is
$$ -d \sin(\theta) $$
(assuming positive $y$ is leftward in the figure, the direction from $D$ to $A$, as implied in the question).
If adding a positive number to $x$ will move you to the right (as in the usual Cartesian coordinates on a graph) then the $x$ formula is reversed and becomes $d \sin(\theta).$

You can verify the formulas with a few test values, such as zero and a right angle. Just be careful to use the correct angle measurements when passing arguments to the sine and cosine functions; most computer math libraries expect these arguments to be measured in radians rather than degrees.

If you already have the coordinates of all the vertices of the square at the time you have to compute the $x$ and $y$ amounts, however, you can avoid the need to use trigonometric functions.

Suppose the $(x,y)$ coordinates of $A$ are $(a_x, a_y)$ and
the $(x,y)$ coordinates of $B$ are $(b_x, b_y)$.
Let $s$ be the length of the side of the square;
you say in the question that $s = 10,$ but if you don't know the size of the square it is easy to compute it from the coordinates:
$$ s = \sqrt{(b_x - a_x)^2 + (b_y - a_y)^2}. $$

Now the amount to add to the $x$ coordinate is just
$$ \frac ds(b_x - a_x) $$
and the amount to add to the $y$ coordinate is just
$$ \frac ds(b_y - a_y). $$

That is, you know that adding $b_x - a_x$ to the $x$ coordinates and $b_y - a_y$ to the $y$ coordinates will move you $s$ units in the desired direction;
to move $d$ units in that direction instead of $s$ units, you just have to move $d/s$ times as far.

---

By the way, if the side of the square is really $10$ cm and the points that appear to be at the intersections of grid lines really are at intersections of grid lines, then your grid lines are approximately
$4.714$ cm apart.
When an actual $10$-cm square is rotated $45$ degrees on a $5$-cm grid,
keeping one vertex on an intersection of grid lines,
the diagonally opposite vertex is visibly below the third grid line above the fixed vertex.